# Unable to plot graph for numpy data getting blank figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    
    # to generage random unifiorm disctribution for 1000 numbers.
    np.random.seed(1000)
    x = np.random.uniform(size =1000) 
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.title("Uniform distribution of the sequence", fontsize =18)
    y = np.where( x > 0.75)
    plt.plot(y)
```

This is the figure I am getting when I run `plt.plot(y)`

[image]

Need to plot graph for the below data but after executing getting blank figure.

[image]

For 'x' I am getting graph but for 'y' I am getting blank graph.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, your y-array is inside a tuple of length 1, try plotting y[0] :)

Comment: You forgot to mention what you want to show in your plot. y is, as you defined it, an index array. How do you intend to use these indexes?

Comment: yes for plt.plot(y[0]) graph is showing

Comment: Good, is it what you wanted? :)

Comment: yes perfectly plotted